# Can I introduce a monster or race as a pet?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, homebrew, animal-companions

I was reading a homebrew *[Sandy Petersen's Cthulhu Mythos for 5e](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/petersengames/sandy-petersens-cthulhu-mythos-for-5e)* and in this issue he adds a breed called Dreamlands Cat, but this breed looks more like a pet than a player.

Deeper in this same homebrew he presents Dreamlands Cat as a monster, I haven't finished reading the book completely.

But my question is: Is there an official D&D rule where I can treat a monster as a pet ally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jeremy Crawford, Lead Rules Designer for D&D 5e, has talked about this a number of times in various interviews, and even on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/1023361783241666560?lang=en), he said:

> Want your D&D character to have a pet/companion?
>
> Here’s a little secret: you don’t need special rules for this. Through roleplaying and ability checks (most likely Animal Handling or Persuasion), you can have a buddy, as long as your DM is OK adding a creature to the group. #DnD

This implies that the D&D team hasn't added any rules about pets in general. However, giving a "pet" that has stats, actions and abilities steps on the uniqueness of classes that have pets like Beast Master Rangers, casters with the *find familiar* spell (especially Pact of Chain Warlocks), Paladins' *find steed spells*, Artificers' Homunculus infusion, Artificer's Turret, etc.

Leaving the pet with abilities in the DM's control and having it work for the group might be a way to prevent abuse. We see this a little bit on  Critical Role Campaign 2 with the blink dog, Sprinkles, and the run away owl, for instance.

### Pet As Sidekick

The other option that would work is the rules in Tasha's about [sidekicks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/dungeon-masters-tools#Sidekicks):

> A sidekick can be any type of creature with a stat block in the *[Monster Manual](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm)* or another D&D book, but the challenge rating in its stat block must be 1/2 or lower. You take that stat block and add to it, as explained in the “[Gaining a Sidekick Class](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/dungeon-masters-tools#GainingaSidekickClass)” section.

Comment: I think the important point here is that the ally creature *acts on its own* -- it belongs to the DM, just like any NPC that's temporarily with the party. James the Tracker, Meepo the Kobold, and a pet cat are not functionally different. A familiar or animal companion has rules text that says it does more or less exactly what its master wants, but a horse, wolf, commoner, or dreamcat is going to act like a horse, wolf, commoner, or dreamcat, and it'll take some effort to make it go against that nature.

Comment: I hasten to clarify that I *almost always* let a player control any companion NPCs in combat, just to take that off my shoulders at DM (cuz I've got plenty to do already and watching me run combat rolls against myself isn't fun), but I reserve the right to reach in and say "Oh, no, he won't do that. He's too scared to come close!" (or whatever makes sense for the NPC in that scenario)

Answer (score 1):

### Yes.

D&D 5e has some rules and discussion for monster allies, hirelings, contacts, sidekicks etc - several spells summon an ally for the party, and Find Familiar is very common in most groups and results in a pet-like summoned small animal.

### None of them are particularly appropriate for the normal process of owning a pet or training an animal to help you out.

There are some vague references to Animal Handling, but only the vaguest (most are literally on twitter).  There are no specific rules for training, taking care of, or utilizing, animals or monsters.  None that I can find.

### This is mostly a good thing.

It's a complex and detailed topic with a lot of potential outcomes - the party enslaving a tribe of goblins and using them to dig into the collapsed dragon's warren is a very different situation to the party thief adopting a kitten and taking it everywhere with her.

A simple or vague rule is thus likely to cause more confusion than help to a GM trying to decide how a gumshoe warforged's pet Mythos Cat affects things and whether it can be coaxed down from a tree or not in time to catch the 5:45 Lightning Rail to Sharn.

**If you want a monster, animal, or npc to travel with or help the party, that is your prerogative as the GM.**  The exact details of how much they help, how much they hinder, what their goals are, which skills can be used on them etc are also up to you - in much the same way as any social encounter works.

Although some GMs find the logistics of allowing the party to amass a small army of allies, slaves, hirelings, pets, beasts of burden etc will slow down the game and remove focus from the PCs (hard to get excited about killing a dragon if none of the player characters leave their armoured command tent), others don't, and most parties have npcs or allies with them, even if it's just the paladin's favourite horse, Rembrandt.

So, in short; there are no (or few) explicit rules on this subject.  If it's related to handling an animal, Wisdom + Animal Handling is a good bet but not always the go-to - for example an intelligent or Awakened animal may require Charisma Persuasion instead.  What exact DCs, how helpful the animal is, or how many challenges it causes the party, are up to the GM and should as usual be adjudicated with an eye to what makes an interesting story and game.